# Layer property refuses to act as anything other than integer when named "SERVICE"

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, features, propertyname

I've been trying to add a new property to a vector layer named SERVICE, this property should be a string. I am able to create this property no problem, and the type is stated to be QString in layer properties.

[image: Layer Properties]

However, when I then open the feature attributes window to edit this property on a feature, the field appears and acts as an Integer, accepting only numbers and showing the adjustment arrows.

[image: Feature Attributes]

This strange behaviour disappears if I change the name of the attribute, even if I change it simply to "Service". For some reason the all caps version of this name seems to cause the field to act as an integer, even though it remains registered as a string in the layer properties.

I'd be interested to see if others are able to reproduce this behaviour, and if anyone knows why it is the case.

Comment: I could not reproduce the behaviour: I'm able to create an attribute called `SERVICE`, formatted as string, and add text to it, using a layer saved as Geopackage. Please add some information: how is your layer saved? In your first screenshot, the field has a length of `0`: that might be a problem.

Comment: If you enter integers, save this: are the numbers saved? If you than again toggle editing and try to introduce a string and save it: what happens?

Comment: I can't reproduce in QGIS 318.1

Comment: Layer is saved as GeoJSON. Changing field length had no effect.
Thanks all for trying this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon returning to this problem this evening it seems to have resolved itself.

Likely the solution was simply restarting either QGIS or the computer itself, so if anyone else comes across this bug then this, as usual, would be a great place to start.